# How to detect when permission is canceled when app running

Tags: android

I have an app the used permission for read and write external storage.
I asking for the permission only in a specific place.
The problem is when user change (only canceled) the permission the app clear the cache or some thing like this. I don't know how to handle this.
I using LG 4.

In manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
<activity android:name=".main.MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
...
```

Some devices the app is crashed (tablet version 23, other device version 28)

Comment: If you mean the user revoked the permission from the Settings app, your process will be terminated at that point.

Comment: But how I can detect it?

Comment: You check whether you hold the permission on every run of your app.

Comment: The problem is that I don't using the permission yet.
I just return to the app and all the data disappear.

Comment: Your process can be terminated at any time while it is not in the foreground. That is not unique to the user revoking a permission. Apparently, you are assuming that some global (`static`) data is always there, and it is not. You need to understand that your process can go away and get restarted at any point, and so any such data may or may not be there. And, you need to write your app such that you can deal with such cached data is missing.

Comment: Can I detect when it happened???

Comment: No. There is no difference, from Android's standpoint, between process invocations. The simplest solution is for you to stop relying so much on that sort of cached data.

Comment: You have to use android runtime permission. Check for permission everytime before executing your code. If you are not using runtime permission yet then you have to start using it. From Android M it only supports runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check permissions before using them.
Try to use [Understanding App Permissions](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Understanding-App-Permissions) as a reference

Comment: I'm not using it.
For example I have fragment that export file. before I export the file I ask for permission. But this isn't the issue.
After the app lunch, I go to the settings of the app and canceling the permission. Now I return to the app and poof!!! all the data disappear

Comment: You have to use them

Answer (score 0):

You can't listen when the permission changed. But you can run a service that checks for permission every second or something. But I assume you want to know when the permission changed before android delete the data.

What you want doesn't exist because it's by design, if the user doesn't want your app writing anything to their phone, then android will prevent/delete it. This prevents apps with malicious intents.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, this is rather niche case so forcing everyone to implement a pattern and/or fallback for that would be just a huge headache for everyone.

To prevent issues when user revokes permission that was previously granted system kills your app process instantly.
That way upon restart it can properly check for available permissions.